# Why is the content of my original ArrayList sorted, if I sort only a copy of it in another ArrayList?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, visual-studio-2012, arraylist

I don't understand, why the content of my original ArrayList will be sorted, if I copy it and then sort (only) this copy. This is my used code snippet:

`Dim LatSorted As ArrayList = arLat
 LatSorted.Sort()`

The ArrayList `arLat` contains Latitudes (unsorted coordinates with type double). If I copy the entire content to a new ArrayList called `LatSorted` nothing happens to the original data as expected. But as soon as I sort the newly filled ArrayList `LatSorted`, the original ArrayList will be sorted too.

*I found a way to fix it:

If I use the command 
`Dim LatSorted As ArrayList = arLat.Clone` it works as expected.*

Again: Why does the .Sort - command for the new ArrayList touch my original ArrayList too?

Comment: There is no _new_ ArrayList.  ArrayLists's are reference types.  Your first line of code did not create a copy of the ArrayList, it only created a new reference to the same ArrayList.  Both variables point to the same ArrayList.  But as you discovered, calling Clone created a copy of the ArrayList.  Be aware, however, that if the ArrayList has reference types in it, the Clone method may not actually make copies of those objects.  You may just get copies of the references.

Answer (score 2):

The new ArrayList is actually just a new reference to the old ArrayList. Therefore, if you sort the new one, the old one gets sorted as well.

'Clone' is exactly what you need to maak a really new ArrayList.